# ManyToManyField IntegrityError in Django - why?

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have *News* and *Page* models, and *News* has two fields referencing to *Page*:

```
chapter   = models.ForeignKey('pages.Page', 
     verbose_name='Main chapter', 
     limit_choices_to={'type__in':['news','speech']}, 
     related_name='news'
)

add_chapters = models.ManyToManyField('pages.Page', blank=True, null=True, 
        verbose_name='Show also on', 
        limit_choices_to={'allow_add_news':True},
        related_name="added_news"
)
```

The problem is that if I'm trying to save *News* from django admin (with some pages selected for add_chapters) - I get the

> **IntegrityError** (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails
>   (`site`.`news_news_add_chapters`,
>   CONSTRAINT `news_id_refs_id_479506ad`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`news_id`) REFERENCES
>   `news_news` (`id`))')

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This works OK for me with Django 1.2 and sqlite and mysql.  I think your db scheme is wrong.  Try it on a fresh db and check if it is working.

(Check your code - keep in mind that `type` is a python built_in.  Did you use `type` instead of `self.type` somewhere?).

The code I used:

```
# models.py
class Page(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="news")
    allow_add_news = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class News(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    chapter   = models.ForeignKey(Page, 
     verbose_name='Main chapter', 
     limit_choices_to={'type__in':['news','speech']}, 
     related_name='news'
    )

    add_chapters = models.ManyToManyField(Page, blank=True, null=True, 
            verbose_name='Show also on', 
            limit_choices_to={'allow_add_news':True},
            related_name="added_news"
    )
```